# Where should I stop a service?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a broadcast receiver in my application.
When I receive a broadcast I pass the content to a service to decode it.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("xxx.yyy.zzz")) {
        Log.d("Receiver", "Intent received from server!");

        byte[] data = intent.getByteArrayExtra("Data");
        String params = intent.getStringExtra("Params");

        Intent i = new Intent(context, DecodeService.class);
        i.putExtra("Data", data);
        i.putExtra("Params", params);

        context.startService(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on the content, I start an appropriate activity from this service.

Now I have some questions about how to manage this service.

- Where should I stop this service? Should I stop it after starting an activity from it and start it again when I receive a broadcast? Or should I let it run while the application is active and stop it when the application is exited.
- What would be the advantage of binding to this service? And can I bind to a service from a broadcastreceiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using `Service` just to decode and start an `Activity`. Instead, I would suggest you to ditch the service part and try to accommodate decoding and launching your activity from the `BroadcastReceiver` class.

For simple tasks, dont get involved with services. It will be a lot easier to expect your application's behavior when not using services.

In case you really want to use service, then I would suggest you to read about [**IntentService**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). It is also a type of service which runs in the background, does its job on a separate thread and automatically gets killed at the end.

Comment: Thx, you're right, I placed the code in my receiver for now. When the code gets more complicated and larger I'll think about using the intentService. Seems exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if your decoding part is not time consuming(network comm.. etc) you better do that in `BroadcastReceiver`. In case you really want to use service..

You can stop your service as soon as start your `Activity`(starting Activity from a service is not recommended though, you can use `Notification` instead).

You can not bind to a service from `BroadCastReceiver`, because `bindService()` is asynchronous, and the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) says once `onReceive()` is returned `BroadCastReceiver` is free to be garbage collected.